# How to add symbols automatically in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm beginning programming with C# and have a question:

I have a string of character like `abcdef123456789`. But the string is too long, therefore I want to add `:` automatically, after the second, fourth, six .... symbol.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking. Maybe post some of your code that you are having problem with? That my help understanding your question.

Comment: I am having some difficulty figuring out exactly what it is you're asking as well. "Too long" how? Too long for what? And, "add ':' automatically" ? As opposed to what, doing it manually? What is the purpose of the ':' in this scenario?

Comment: Use a while loop and some string logic to insert the colon. You want us to do your homework ?

Comment: The string is too long is just an expression gentlemen, he want to cut it in pieces with  a delimiter every 2 chars

Comment: Well... then I concur, we're indeed doing someone's coding homework now, where they themselves should in fact have spent some more time on their English homework before even posting the question in the first place.

Comment: 3 answers already, people don't mind doing someone's homework and the OP learns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in method that does something like that. You just have to put the separators in there by looping through the string.

You can loop though the characters and put them in a `StringBuilder`, adding a colon at every other character:

```
string input = "abcdef123456789";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int cnt = 0;
foreach (char c in input) {
  if (cnt == 2) {
    builder.Append(':');
    cnt = 0;
  }
  builder.Append(c);
  cnt++;
}
string output = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach. I've attempted to make it as readable as possible, so hopefully it makes sense to you.

```
var s = "abcdef123456789";

var charsChanged = new List<char>();

for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    charsChanged.Add(s[i]);

    var evenCharacter = i % 2 != 0;
    var atEndOfString = i == s.Length - 1;

    if (evenCharacter && !atEndOfString)
    {
        charsChanged.Add(':');
    }
}

var updatedString = string.Concat(charsChanged));
```

`updatedString` will equal `ab:cd:ef:12:34:56:78:9`.

This approach makes use of the modulus operator (`%`) to determine if we're at an even or odd character. For more examples, check [this out](http://www.dotnetperls.com/odd).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StringBuilder and do something like this:

```
string sourceStr = "123456789";
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
foreach(char c in sourceStr){
    s.append(c);
    s.append(":");
}
```

Comment: That is a separator after every character

Comment: Yes, but his question is vague.